# using try except with itk on OTB

Tags: python, error-handling, except, roi

I want to extract ROI of Sentinel 2 images, several of them aren't on my ROI. I have treatment to do afterwards in the same loop; for it to be faster I'd like to pass to another image if the error :

```
2020-02-12 12:06:10 (WARNING) ExtractROI: Could not extract the ROI as it is out of the input image.

2020-02-12 12:06:10 (FATAL) ExtractROI: itk::ERROR: MultiChannelExtractROI(00000013FC1D5890): Extraction Region not consistent with output image
```

occurs. I found that Try/Except would apply to my situation but I have no clue how to do it since it's not python error.

I'm extracting my ROI as such, on python / linux :

```
os.system('otbcli_ExtractROI -in path/to/input  -out path/to/output -mode fit -mode.fit.vect path/to/vector')
```

I tried to do

```
try: 
   os.system('otbcli_ExtractROI -in path/to/input  -out path/to/output -mode fit -mode.fit.vect path/to/vector')
except itk.Exception:
    print('Image not in ROI')
```

but it doesn't work, do you have solutions for me ?